# Using a US DOD CAC on Android

Tags: applications, hardware

The US Department of Defence (DOD) uses a Common Access Card (CAC) for authentication on a number of externally available websites. It is possible to use the CAC with Firefox on Linux (e.g., see the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Common_Access_Card)). From my understanding, the CAC is a fairly standard smartcard.

Are there smartcard/CAC readers and web browsers that are compatible with Android? If not, are there technical limitations that prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Arg, the military and their acronyms. Anyway yes there are some companies that are TAA compliant (Trade Agreements Act [19 U.S.C. & 2501-2581])

Thursby with PKard is one that is known to have a working model for both CAC or PIV (Personal Identity Verification) cards.
[Reference](http://www.thursby.com/products/pkard-android-app)

Samsung Knox also has a working system and they do have DOD contracts. I believe they are TAA compliant because they are from a friendly foreign country. At what clearance level though I am unsure about because of the foreign country thing. [Reference](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/products/knox-workspace/technical)